# Will adding multiple Pageview Tags in Google Tag Manager record multiple page views?

Tags: google-tag-manager, enhanced-ecommerce

I’m looking at replacing Google Analytics with Google Tag Manager in a web application I have.

I’m working through the [Enhanced Ecommerce](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce) guide to track ecommerce-related events in my application.

In that documentation, under “**See the Tag Configuration for this Example**”, a lot of them say to use a *Pageview* Tag.

I already have a Pageview Tag. Will adding additional Pageview Tags record multiple page views in Analytics? Or are Analytics and Tag Manager intelligent enough to discern what is an *actual* page view and what is a “synthetic” page view for the purpose of recording ecommerce data only?

Also, cheeky bonus question: Some of the examples say to use Trigger: “`event` equals `gtm.dom`”. Is this the same as the “DOM Ready” Trigger available in Tag Manager? Or is a `gtm.dom` event something different?

Answer (score 2):

For eCommerce tracking via GTM you will have to create a new Universal Analytics tag with Track Type: Even not Pageview so there will be no issues with multiple hits. Also, you want the new tag to only fire on the confirmation page.

Use the Debug mode with Tag Assistant to see what is being fired and when.

Comment: A Transaction Tag is for Standard Ecommerce. I’m using Enhanced Ecommerce.

Comment: Sorry I meant to say Track Type: Event.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it will, but you can test this by setting up a temporary page and and placing the tags there to see if it fires multiple times in the real time reporting.